# How can I undo git push -f origin master

Tags: github

[image]

I ran git push -f origin master command, how do I revert to initial state?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Fatih Yılmaz have you tried this
https://dev.to/isabelcmdcosta/how-to-undo-the-last-commit--31mg i had the same  issue trying the revert it doing this